# jQuery UI - revolving text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI, I'm trying to do this: when I hover over a text, I would like the text to fade out and let another text fade in (replacing the old text).
This could easily be done with standard jQuery, **but** I would like to add some effect to the fading texts: the one I would like most is that every letter disappears by rotating on itself, kind of a combination between the classic **mosaic effect** and the **anagram effect** in keynote presentations.

And may I take advantage of the kindness of SO people: is there a simple way to search through all the functions provided by jQuery UI? I mean, can I search somewhere for "text effect" and find all the effects that are nice applied on text?

Comment: Hi, take a look at this page: http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/ It lists several effects that are optionally built in to the JQuery UI JS package you can download.  Each effect has a demo to show how it works.

Comment: Ok, this at least solves the problem concerning the "where to find effects" part. Still jQuery UI effects are not as much as I though, I mean, the effect I described in my question (is it clear by the way?) should be a pretty common one...

Comment: Is this the type of effect you're looking for? http://kiro.me/projects/textualizer.html Kinda matrix'y...

Comment: God, that was **perfect**. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a link with a Mosaic type effect: http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/ (Demo: http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/ )